# restore tensor flow model and run it with input

Tags: python, neural-network, tensor

I have a model which takes int input x and create mean and variance of vector of size x. 
I am able to save this model , but want to restore , run it by passing x value. I am able to restore also but do not know how to execute it after line

```
saver.restore(sess, './mean_var.ckpt')
```

For different x. Can I use feed_dict for this ? Please help me fix this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def mean_var(x):
    vec = tf.random_normal([x])
    mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(vec, [0], keep_dims=True)
    return  mean, variance 
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    output = mean_var(x)
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    _ = tf.Variable(initial_value='fake_variable')
    saver = tf.train.Saver()


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(_.initializer)
        #val = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: 4})
        #print(val[0], val[1])
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "./mean_var.ckpt")

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    _ = tf.Variable(initial_value='fake_variable')
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(_.initializer)
        saver.restore(sess, './mean_var.ckpt')
```

Comment: You can use feed_dict yes. Running it works the same way as before saving. After restore, do: `val = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: 4})`

Comment: when I do this after restoring .ckpt file , I get TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", dtype=int32) is not an element of this graph.   It works in my first graph (commented line) but not in second.

Comment: Remove the `tf.reset_default_graph()` line

Comment: my ask is create a graph , save model , reset graph  and load saved model and run it for different input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to restore and predict:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./mean_var.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")   
        output = mean_var(x)
        y_pred = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x:4})
        print(y_pred)
```

And, one more thing give a name to the placeholder `x` like below:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name="x")
```

**Full code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
def mean_var(x):
    vec = tf.random_normal([x])
    mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(vec, [0], keep_dims=True)
    return  mean, variance 

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name="x")
    output = mean_var(x)
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    _ = tf.Variable(initial_value='fake_variable')
    saver = tf.train.Saver()


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(_.initializer)
        val = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: 4})
        print(val[0], val[1])
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "./mean_var/mean_var.ckpt")

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./mean_var/mean_var.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./mean_var/'))
        #saver.restore(sess, './mean_var/mean_var.ckpt')
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")   
        output = mean_var(x)
        y_pred = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x:4})
        print(y_pred)
```